# Run as Admin - without being local admin?

Tags: windows, security, windows-7

Is there any way, on Windows 7, to let users have the "Run as Administrator" option available without giving them full local admin rights?

It will grant them the same level of access to the machine, but without being admin all the time. I like the way OSX solves this (asking the user for their password when they try something that requires elevated privileges), but I haven't found anything similar for Win7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 has User Account Control (UAC) that does pretty much the same thing, and you can [customize it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835564(WS.10).aspx), although it sounds like you have it disabled.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the possibility to customize UAC. "User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode" is the closest I've found - it will replace the standard dialog box with a password-prompt.

Answer (score 0):

HI I think you might be looking for the runas command:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294676

Also check here for command line options:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294676

You could create a simple bat file.

Just like mac os this requires an administrator password.